# Wpf + Prism навигация перерисовывает DataGridHeader Style?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

Задавал вопрос с сообществе [Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1131). Brian Lagunas уверяет, что это не проблема Prism.

Суть Wpf 4.5 + Prism 6.3:

`CustomersView` с `DataGrid` и реализованным фильтром в `ColumnHeader`:

```
<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Grid x:Name="gridColumnHeader">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenterColumnHeader"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="filter" Grid.Row="1" Height="30" Width="30"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

Пользователь устанавливает фильтр в столбце `Name(filter.Text = 11)` и совершает навигацию для редактирования выбранного `Customer` в `EditCustomerView`. После редактирования `IRegionNavigationJournal.GoBack()` возвращаемся в `CustomersView`. Все изменения прошли, но в заголовке потерся фильтр в дефолтное значение(`filter.Text = string.Empty`). Перерисовывается `ColumnHeaderStyle`? Для эксперимента положил на `CustomersView` `TextBox`, навигация не трет `TextBox.Text`.

MCVE
`CustomersViewModel`

```
public class CustomersViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
{
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

    public CustomersViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;

        Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
        Customers.Add(new Customer { Id = 1, Name = "Samsung", Type = 1 });
        Customers.Add(new Customer { Id = 2, Name = "Apple", Type = 1 });
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Customer> _customers;
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers
    {
        get { return _customers; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _customers, value);
        }
    }

    public ICommand AddCustomerCommand { get { return new DelegateCommand<object>(ExecuteAddCustomer); } }
    private void ExecuteAddCustomer(object parameter)
    {
        _regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", new Uri("CustomerView", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    public virtual bool IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public virtual void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
    }

    public virtual void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
    }
}
```

`CustomerViewModel`

```
public class CustomerViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
{
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;
    private IRegionNavigationJournal _navigationJournal;

    public CustomerViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
    }

    public ICommand SaveCommand { get { return new DelegateCommand<object>(ExecuteSaveCommand); } }
    private void ExecuteSaveCommand(object parameter)
    {
        if (_navigationJournal.CanGoBack)
        {
            _navigationJournal.GoBack();
        }
    }

    public virtual bool IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public virtual void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {

    }

    public virtual void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        _navigationJournal = navigationContext.NavigationService.Journal;
    }
}
```

`CustomersView` до навигации с установленным фильтром в `Column.Name = 11`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`CustomersView` после навигации с удаленным фильтром:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример кода - [PrismNavigation](https://yadi.sk/d/SXU4AqGA3LdhDz)

Спасибо.

Comment: ...предоставьте `MCVE`

Comment: отредактировал первый пост

Comment: Ну, я не спец по работе с DataGrid, но похоже, что фильтры являются частью UI и при навигации не сохраняются, как и любой visual state (к примеру, позиция выделенного текста в текстбоксе). Попробуйте и правда сохранить ваши фильтры перед началом навигации.

Comment: Похоже на правду, спасибо за помощь.